# How to update a Widget inside a List

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of chats, and I want to show on each chat card, if there's a new message that the user hasn't read.

The list is in a StatefulWidget, the list contains refactored cards that are also StatefulWidgets, I also made the code to work with Firestore to check if the user has read the message, but still I don't know what's happening, because it doesn't update the icon of unread messages.

The data changes in the database, but it doesn't in the chat card. If I reload the app, because the cards are rebuilt, then it does change.

Here's the chat card code:

```
bool hasUnreadMessages = false;
  void unreadMessagesVerifier() {
    setState(() {
      _firestore.collection('chatRoom').document(_chatRoomID).get().then((data) async {
        hasUnreadMessages = await data['hasUnreadMessages'];
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    unreadMessagesVerifier();
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: Text(
                      widget.lastMessage,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                hasUnreadMessages
                    ? Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 5, 0),
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 7,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      )
                    : SizedBox(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      onTap: widget.onTap,
    ); // ChatCard
  }
```

If more info is needed, do let me know!

========================================================================
**EDIT:**

Fixed thanks to @Pedro R.

I just had to move the SetState() and check the **mounted**

```
void unreadMessagesVerifier() {
  _firestore.collection('chatRoom').document(_chatRoomID).get().then((data) async {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          hasUnreadMessages = data['hasUnreadMessages'];
        });
      }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem lies in the way you are calling setState.
Try calling it after the future finishes.
Like this:

```
  void unreadMessagesVerifier() {
        _firestore.collection('chatRoom').document(_chatRoomID).get().then((data) =>
              data['hasUnreadMessages'].then(result){
                setState((){
                    hasUnreadMessages = result;
                });
              }); 
   }
```

Sorry for the formatting by the way.

Comment: `data['hasUnreadMessages'].then(result){` the then in there is giving me an error _Function expressions can't be named._

Comment: You were right, I was calling the `SetState()` in the wrong place. I changed it to where you have it, and **ignored the reformatting** and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [StatefulBuilder class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html), it rebuilds the particular Widget which it wraps based upon the value getting updated

So, `hasUnreadMessage` will be used to update the `Container()`. Do something like this

```
StatefulBuilder(
  builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState){
    // here you return the data based upon your bool value
    return hasUnreadMessages ? Container(
         margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 5, 0),
         child: CircleAvatar(
           radius: 7,
           backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
         )
    ) : SizedBox();
  }
)
```